# Left hand bass technique

Tags: piano, technique

It is well known that one of the common mistakes a learning pianist makes is to use the left hand “too loudly” when playing.

I know I have in the past but I have managed to control my left hand through brain control.

I also found it more controlled when I drop my wrist slightly when playing bass lines which tends to help me control my enthusiasm!

I am also aware of different techniques such as attack, flat hands play, between keys...etc...

However,

In the quest of improvement, do different techniques/hand positions exists in order to control even more?

**EDIT**

I achieve different sound levels by thinking of how much weight of fingers, wrists, arms... to place. So say, Forte would using all my arm weight from the elbow

Comment: Are you talking about left hand _bass_ or left hand _chords_? In my experience, bass lines are usually _too quiet_ when played by pianists (except when they're _doubling_ a proper bass instrument, in which case they should really just stop it entirely...).

Comment: Just left hand use in general. See other comment

Answer (score 2):

Lack of control is certainly something all beginner pianists have to work through.  I wouldn't say it was particularly a left hand problem.  But if it is for you, let's try to help.

I'm a bit worried about your idea of dropping the wrist.  It could stop you using hand and arm weight.  But you can do that without a low wrist.  Keep the usual 'curved fingers' position and make sure your hand and arm aren't flopping up and down.

But this isn't something we can fix with words.  A teacher, watching you play, can sort this out with you.

Comment: My hand doesn’t drop that much. It’s just lower than the right at time, I find I have more control. I still have excellent relaxation and full arm motion. I am self taught so no teacher. I just wanted to know what others do.... and I was assessed by a teacher and no real problems were found....